# Vectors And Merging

Tags: c++, vector, merge

For this vectors and merging assignment, we are supposed to read in user inputted strings and sort them alphabetically.  I got the first two parts, but when I am putting the sorted elements in the new vector, it says that my new vector is out of range.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {


    vector<string> que1;
    vector<string> que2;
    vector<string> que_merge;

    string firstName;
    string secondName;
    int counterq1 = 0;
    int counterq2 = 0;

    cout << "Enter queues: " << endl;

    bool check = true;
    while(check) {
        cin >> firstName;
        if (firstName == "ENDQ"){
            check = false;
        }
        else{
            que1.push_back(firstName);
            counterq1++;
            check = true;
        }
    }
//    que1.resize(counterq1);

    bool check2 = true;
    while (check2) {
        cin >> secondName;
        if (secondName == "ENDQ") {
            check2 = false;
        } else {
            que2.push_back(secondName);
            counterq2++;
        }
    }
//    que2.resize(counterq2);

    cout << "que1: " << counterq1 << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < que1.size(); i++) {
        cout << que1.at(i) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "que2: " << counterq2 << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j < que2.size(); j++) {
        cout << que2.at(j) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "que_merge: " << counterq1 + counterq2 << endl;



    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (1){
        if (i >= counterq1 || j >= counterq2){
            break;
        }
        if(que1.at(i) < que2.at(j)){
            que_merge.push_back(que1.at(i));
            i++;
        }
        else{
            que_merge.push_back(que2.at(j));
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }


    if (que1.empty()){
        for (int m = j; m < counterq2; m++){
            que_merge.push_back(que2.at(m));
        }
    } else {
        for (int l = i; l < counterq1; ++l) {
            que_merge.push_back(que1.at(l));
        }
    }



    for (int l = 0; l < (counterq1+counterq2); l++) {
        cout << que_merge.at(l) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please indent all the code by 4 spaces

Comment: Why your loops to "merge"? Why not simply [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) both vectors at the `end` of the new vector? If you want the elements sorted, then there's [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) once you merged the vectors.

Comment: Or if you don't want duplicates, there's always [`std::set_union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union).

Comment: Why do you count the number of elements in the vector? just use `vector.size()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that these lines:

```
if (que1.empty()){
    for (int m = j; m < counterq2; m++){
        que_merge.push_back(que2.at(m));
    }
} else {
    for (int l = i; l < counterq1; ++l) {
        que_merge.push_back(que1.at(l));
    }
}
```

doesn't do what you expect.

As far as I can see, your idea is to merge the remaining element from either `que1` or `que2`.

However, that is not what you get from this code as the elements in `que1` and `que2` is never erased. In other words - the check for an empty queue is rather meaningless and you can't be sure that all elements are added to `que_merge`

So when you do:

```
for (int l = 0; l < (counterq1+counterq2); l++) {
    cout << que_merge.at(l) << endl;
}
```

you may read beyond the number of elements in `que_merge`

Tip:

Don't count the number of elements your self. Use `size()` (like `que_merge.size()`) instead. For instance:

```
for (int l = 0; l < que_merge.size(); l++) {
    cout << que_merge.at(l) << endl;
}
```

or a range based loop like:

```
for (const auto& s : que_merge) {
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

Comment: No need for a reference `&` on the range-based for-loop.

Comment: @JiveDadson Correct - there is no **need** for it as the code will produce the same result without using reference. However, depending on the compiler and how the code is optimized, it may give a performance difference. Without reference there may be a copying of each element.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Use std::merge and std::sort, not necessarily in that order.

If the assignment says you can't do it the C++ way, that you have to write it all out, you can do it the engineer's way: Find an example that works, and crib it.

There are two possible implementations of std::merge on this page: [All about C++ merge](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge)